# Is there a way to make a HTTP/2 request from Salesforce Apex?

Tags: apex, httprequest

I have setup a [Cloudflare Service Worker](https://echoecho.mpg.workers.dev/) that echos the HTTP and TLS version used to connect.

Service Worker code:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => 
  event.respondWith(
    new Response(
      event.request.cf.httpProtocol + " " +
      event.request.cf.tlsVersion,

      {status: 200}
    )
  )
);
```

Then, I made a GET request using the anonymous execution window.

```java
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://echoecho.mpg.workers.dev/');
request.setMethod('GET');

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

System.debug(response.getBody());
```

This produces the output: `HTTP/1.1 TLSv1.2`.

The [only reference to HTTP/2 that I could find](https://engineering.salesforce.com/the-full-picture-on-http-2-and-hol-blocking-7f964b34d205) was not very helpful.

Is there any way to force Salesforce to use the `HTTP/2` protocol instead of `HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: Slightly curious - why does it mater to you?

Comment: @dzh I want to send Apple Push Notifications from Salesforce, and the APNS Server will reject all connections not made via `HTTP/2` and `TLS1.2`, as per [the specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html).

Comment: Any reason you can’t use mobile push? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_overview.htm

Comment: @muenzpraeger No, I want to make the request from an Apex class.

Comment: Which you can do using mobile push.

Comment: @muenzpraeger Mobile push is not suitable for our needs. I also need to talk to some business servers that only support `HTTP/2`. Is there no way to send a `HTTP/2` request from within Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000XwHE):

> Salesforce does not support HTTP/2 protocol currently.
>
> Related link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015DEtQAM

Answer (score 2):

The Apex language does not give you any control over what protocol is used when making callouts. The [`Http`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_http.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_http) class has methods only for `send()` and `toString()`, with the former accepting no overloads which would allow you to configure behavior. The [`HttpRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) class has numerous setter methods, but none of them would allow you to specify protocol either.

Comment: I do not WANT to specify the protocol, I just want to know if Salesforce will connect to a server that only supports `HTTP/2`?

Comment: If you visit the [service worker](https://echoecho.mpg.workers.dev/) from your browser, you will see something like `HTTP/2 TLSv1.3`. This is because all modern browsers will use HTTP/2 if the server supports it, and fallback to HTTP/1.1 otherwise. As you can see from my testing, Salesforce used the HTTP/1.1 protocol even though Cloudflare supports HTTP/2. Does Salesforce support the HTTP/2 protocol for outgoing requests?